# Simplest way to eliminate redundant constraints due to a new cut

Tags: linear-programming, optimization, constraint, polyhedra, linear-algebra

I have a polyhedral set for constraining $x$: 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{+} : \ Dx \leq d \}
\end{align}
where $D \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, d \in \mathbb{R}^m$. I find the Chebyshev center of this polyhedron, by solving: 
\begin{array}{ll}
\max &\, r\\
\text{s.t.} & D_i^\top x_c  + r \|D_i^\top\| \leq d_i \ \text{for }i =1,\ldots,m
\end{array}
Now I have this $x_c$, Chebyshev center of $\mathcal{P}.$ I split this polyhedron by two parts. Let $r \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector. I  can divide $\mathcal{P}$ by two halves by adding $r^\top x_c \leq r^\top x$ or $r^\top x_c \geq r^\top x$ to have $\mathcal{P}^\geq, \mathcal{P}^{\leq}$.

Now, in this way, there are definitely new redundant constraints. I have seen some ways to find these redundant constraints, but my case is more specific since I divide based on the center. Therefore, I am wondering if there is an easy way to address this issue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a partial answer, [Telgen (1977)](https://ageconsearch.umn.edu/record/272154/files/erasmus091.pdf) has shown that eliminating all redundant inequalities is LP-equivalent, i.e. in general not easier than solving linear programs. Clearly, this does not exclude heuristics (e.g. [A heuristic approach for identification of redundant constraints in linear programming models](https://doi.org/10.1080/00207160601014148)) or a better strategy for removing (a subset of) the redundant inequalities in your special case.

Telgen, J., *On redundancy of systems of linear inequalities*, Rep. 7718, Econometric Institute, Erasmus University Rotterdam, 1977.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. TBH, I am not solving an LP. I am solving a very hard non-convex problem. But, my constraints are linear. Therefore, reducing is very important to me. The heuristic paper you shared says LP, I hope it works for linear contsraints as well.

Comment: Yes, it looks for the objective as well :\

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/69667

Here they show the standard LP-procedure. Thanks to your Telgen (1977) reference I will just say that it is LP-equivalent, and here is an LP (then back to MO answer).

I was wondering if my case is easier to detect somehow since I take a ball where I center $x_c$ , so maybe we can just look at the polyhedral inequalities and understand which one is redundant etc..